# Excel don't created on local server HRESULT 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, hresult

I made an program that copies `GridView` to Excel. It worked well on localhost. Than published it on local network it still opens pages etc. but gets stuck on defining workbook

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook WBook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```

And gives `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC)` error.

I tried different solutions that I found from internet (creating desktop folder in systemprofile [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408336/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x800a03ec), through administrator [Windows 7 .net Excel .SaveAs() Error Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981395/windows-7-net-excel-saveas-error-exception-from-hresult-0x800a03ec)) but didn't solve problem.

Comment: While not a solution, you should *really* avoid using Excel like this.

Comment: Do you have Excel installed on the server you are trying to use it on?

Comment: Yes I define my computer as server using IIS

Comment: Is there anyone can HELP

Comment: Long shot: Some .dll's are missing for creating the Excel. Open your project>References>Right click on the Excel dll>Set Copy Local to true and deploy your project again.

Comment: thank you. it worked in a way. Now program don't give an error but dont open the excel anyway.