# Excel is not working in Windows 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Iam trying to export Some datas to Excel in my asp.net project. It is working fine on every version of windows except Wiindows 8.
It throwing One Exception

```
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException 
(0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC  at 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookClass.SaveAs
(Object Filename, Object FileFormat, Object Password, 
Object WriteResPassword, Object ReadOnlyRecommended, 
Object CreateBackup, XlSaveAsAccessMode AccessMode, 
Object ConflictResolution, Object AddToMru, Object TextCodepage, 
Object TextVisualLayout, Object Local)
```

I have already added the Desktop Folder for the Folder structure in `C:\\windows\sysWow64\Config\SystemProfile\ Desktop (Mine is 64 bit)`

Why it is making problem with Windows 8 ? Anyone help Me?

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981395/windows-7-net-excel-saveas-error-exception-from-hresult-0x800a03ec/1986575#1986575 this is for windows 7..check with yours whether it helps..

Comment: Sorry iam already tried.. Anyway thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work, After creating the Desktop folder in the mentioned path, check the permissins of modify the folder and some other. If it is not there means u can give all the permissions.
And also Check wheather the Component service of the Microsoft Excel is present with all the permissions.

Comment: This Link also helped to enable the permissions with COM Objects.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981395/windows-7-net-excel-saveas-error-exception-from-hresult-0x800a03ec/1986575#1986575    Thanks sachu